# which is faster, or is it just considered bad code

Tags: java, mysql, database, coding-style

Lets say that we have a MySQL backend with a table having its primary-key defined with the UNIQUE property. We are receiving data from multiple distributed systems all having a the  same/similar implementation..

At some point we will try and batch insert e.g. 10 million documents-rows, but we only want to store the data if we do not violate the unique constraint, which approach would be faster/considered **ok**..?

e.g

```
try {
    //...try and insert the document
} catch(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
    //..do nothing, since this is already stored in the database
    //move on to the next one..
}
```

or

```
//we try to find the document...
if(!documentFound) {
    //we did not find a document with this id, so we can safely insert it..
    //move on to the next one...
}
```

In my head im guessing that in both cases the id we are trying to insert has to be "found" since we have to validate the unique constraint, but which of the two is considered more or less ok in relation to its speed?

Side question: Will the answer/result (in terms of for example speed) be the same for example Mysql in relation to mongoDB?

Comment: do the uniqueness test purely in mysql. If you test in PHP, then try to insert, you open up a race condition where some OTHER instance of the same script could snipe that db "slot" behind your script's back. Of course, you could always use SQL-level table/row locks to prevent this, but those open up other issues.

Comment: I think the first approach is better because you dont have to do a `select` first, especially when you have millions of rows in the database.

Comment: i'm not mysql expert, but i dont think `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` is thrown only when you have duplicate entry, which means it is much more safest solution.

Comment: if we were to look at the actual time it would take for the operation itself then, the lookup have to happen to determine if the key exists in both cases, would it be slower to determine this by issuing a find or throw exception when failing, im thinking throwing 99 million exception if 1 milion new entries might be a bad idea in terms in time?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just use a [INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). That way you dont have to worry if they key already exists? So in your case you can do

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would reserve exceptions to... exceptional cases :) In other words, if something may happen in the normal workflow, I would rather handle the case with a regular `if`. An empty `catch` clause usually suggests there is something wrong.

Also, I would rather use the [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) construct (instead of `ON DUPLICATE` -- it works just fine, but I dislike the hackish `UPDATE id=id`).

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. (...) Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Comment: ok, but if we are interested in knowing if the insert went good or bad, this wont work in a distributed environment if we have multiple systems inserting i guess?, since we have to use LAST_INSERT_ID() to determine if the counter have been incremented, and having multiple systems doing inserts, we cant really rely on this counter i guess?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the ID a record inserted **within the current session** (cf. [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)), so concurrent insertions do not matter. Also, to determine whether the last `INSERT IGNORE` succeeded, I would instead check if a warning was generated (`SHOW WARNINGS`, or the equivalent API call), but I guess this is really only a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on looping over the records and processing them one by one I would suggest yet another approach

**Pseudocode**

1. Create a hashlist
2. Search for the unique key in the hashlist
3. Insert into database if not found. Add the unique key to the hashlist
4. Get next record
5. Goto 2 if not eof.

If you have many duplicates, you'll save yourself a lot of *(relatively)* expensive database calls.